# Getting child elements of the nth div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```html
<div>
  Project Name
</div>
<div>
  Project Description
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    Metadata 1 <!-- I want this -->
  </div>
  <div>
     Metadata 2 <!-- And this -->
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I get `Metadata 1` and `Metadata 2` using `$(elem).find()`?

I'm trying this, but no luck:

```
$(elem).find(div[3]:nth-of-type(1))'  // getting first element of the third div
$(elem).find(div[3]:nth-of-type(2))'  // getting second element of the third div
```

Comment: If only the html page use heading and section elements correctly instead of divs. This would be very easy to solve.

Comment: What is `elem`?

Comment: The best solution would be to improve the HTML code but if you can't and know the structure won't change you can use `$(elem).find('div > div')` if `elem` is a parent element and the are no other `div` that are direct children of another `div`

Answer (score 0):

This would select the immediate div children of the 3rd div. You can use jQuery of course as well: `$('that-selector').text()`

```css
.a-container div:nth-child(3)>div {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

/* 
or safer:
.a-container>div:nth-child(3)>div {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
*/
```

```html
<section class="a-container">

  <div>
    Project Name
  </div>
  <div>
    Project Description
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      Metadata 1
      <!-- I want this -->
    </div>
    <div>
      Metadata 2
      <!-- And this -->
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```